# How to prevent the OTA Jellybean update on Droid RAZR Maxx

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, ota-update, motorola-droid-razr

I have a Motorola Razr Maxx with ICS (4.0.2) on it.  It went and downloaded the JellyBean upgrade, which I do not want to happen.  Each hour the phone prompts me to upgrade.  How can I keep this from happening?  Can I delete the new files for JB and stop the hourly message?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you rooted?

Answer (score 1):

(1) If you have root, you can use Titianium Backup, and uninstall "Device Management 3.0" (or some other version).

(2) OR, [also needs root], remove dmclient.apk, dmclient.odex, cmclient.apk, cmclient.odex from /system/app. Back-up these files first, in case you want to update in the future; you will need these.